NoClassDefFoundError when mvn clean install is executed
Using JUnit 5, I have implemented a test class CalculatorTest (located under src/test/java) in order to test the class Calculator (located under src/main/java). Using mvn clean install at command line, I got a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError referring to the class Calculator. Finally, I have found out that I can avoid this error by adding src/main/java as an additional classpath to the configuration of the Surefire plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>src/main/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration> 
</plugin>

I suppose that the observed error is caused because the test class CalculatorTest is built at first, i.e. before the class Calculator is built (see documentation). Is my understanding correct? Would it not be better to compile the classes from src/main/java at first by default?
In spite of the fact that I have found a solution, I would like to know whether my understanding of the problem is correct.

Why using the source directory src/main/java as additionalClasspath element? What is the reason for that.. Please show the pom file or a link to your project?

The typical scenario is that the main files are compiled before the test files, so your issue indicates something strange going on. You would need to supply much more details for a solution.

You should add the whole pom.xml to your question in order for us to understand what is happening. Usually classes compiled from src/main/java will be part of the test runtime classpath. You should also add the complete stacktrace of the NoClassDefFoundError to further aid analysis.

The classpath entry should not be necessary. Could be that the project setup is incorrect / tests are not where they should be and hence do not know about the actual code. You are correct, tests should be in src/test/java/, but also check the remaining path, make sure code and test folder structure is identical and correctly mirrors the package structure. Please share the output of the $ tree command for you project.
